# Lots of Problems About NSString Reference Count

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have some tests about Mannul Reference Counting in Objective-C.
I run these code below:

```
- (void) test {
    NSData *a1 = [[NSData alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"NSData: %lu", [a1 retainCount]);

    NSMutableData *a2 = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"NSMutableData: %lu", [a2 retainCount]);

    NSObject *a3 = [[NSObject alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"NSObject: %lu", [a3 retainCount]);

    NSString *b1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%@", @"ok"];
    NSLog(@"NSString: %lu", [b1 retainCount]);


    NSString *b2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%@", a3];
    NSLog(@"NSStinrg: %lu", [b2 retainCount]);


    NSString *a = @"abc";
    NSString *b = @"abc";
    NSLog(@"%p", a);
    NSLog(@"%p", b);

}
```

The Console :

```
2016-06-23 16:15:50.490 text[38147:3406036] NSData: 18446744073709551615
2016-06-23 16:15:50.491 text[38147:3406036] NSMutableData: 1
2016-06-23 16:15:50.491 text[38147:3406036] NSObject: 1
2016-06-23 16:15:50.491 text[38147:3406036] NSString: 18446744073709551615
2016-06-23 16:15:50.491 text[38147:3406036] NSStinrg: 1
2016-06-23 16:15:50.491 text[38147:3406036] 0x10359d160
2016-06-23 16:15:50.491 text[38147:3406036] 0x10359d160
```

And I want know why the reference counts of `NSData` and `NSString` are `UINT_MAX`(-1), and `initWithFormat` will make `b2` add a count? Why are the addresses of `a` and `b` same?

Thx a lot.

Comment: [When to use -retainCount?](http://sdarlington.github.io)

Comment: @vikingosegundo haha, you got there before me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empty immutable NSDatas are uniqued to a single instance, which cannot be retained or released (indicated by the UINT_MAX-1 refcount). For the NSString one, %@ is replaced by the result of calling -description on the object, and the -description method of NSString returns self. So you're getting a constant NSString literal there, which is similarly not something that can be retained or released. Constant strings are also uniqued, so there's a single one embedded in your binary at compile time, and no allocations are made.

Comment: Please don't spam unrelated questions

Comment: So `a` and `b` has embedded in binary ai compile time. And in this time, compiler can compare `a` with `b` to judge  whether they are equal? In this way, they share the one address?

Comment: @Desgard_Duan: Objective-C does lots and lots of things to save memory. Including having objects where the pointer is the object itself.

Answer (score 2):

From the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/retainCount)

```
- (NSUInteger)retainCount
```

> This method is of no value in debugging memory management issues.
>   Because any number of framework objects may have retained an object in
>   order to hold references to it, while at the same time autorelease
>   pools may be holding any number of deferred releases on an object, it
>   is very unlikely that you can get useful information from this method.